# <a href="fb//"> open post/video Link in native App?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I want to open specific url post or video from html `<a>` to facebook mobile app.

I can do it on profile and page.
Example :

```
  <a href="fb://page/000000000000" class="small-screen">Open FB App</a>
  <a href="fb://profile/000000000000" class="small-screen">Open FB App</a>
```

I also tried with

```
  <a href="fb://post/000000000000" class="small-screen">Open FB App</a>
  <a href="fb://video/000000000000" class="small-screen">Open FB App</a>
  <a href="fb://page/000000000000/post/000000" class="small-screen">Open FB App</a>
  <a href="fb://page/000000000000/video/000000" class="small-screen">Open FB App</a>
```

But I've no idea how to use this and can't find API guide.
Please kindly help me, advice me it is possible or not.

Comment: Where did you see this working?

Comment: you can test . upper 2 lines .